# Loop worksheets and delete

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to loop worksheets and delete the unwanted. The problem is that I want to loop and delete based on the VBA editor (Names) but I am getting an error. Loop works perfectly. Any help will be appreciated.

**Code:**

```
Sub Remove_Sheets()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        If ws.Name = wsOriginal Or ws.Name = wsRecords Then
        Else
            ws.Delete
        End If

    Next ws

End Sub
```

**Image:**

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem solved. I have replaced:

```
If ws.Name = wsOriginal Or ws.Name = wsRecords Then
```

with:

```
If ws.CodeName = "wsOriginal" Or ws.CodeName = "wsRecords" Then
```